# Convert dictionary values into array sorted by another array

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary

`mydict = {'jon': 12, 'alex': 17, 'jane': 13}`

and I want to create a `np.array` which contains the values `12, 17, 13`, but sorted by another array

`sortby = np.array(['jon', 'jane', 'alex'])`

which should yield the output as

`sorted_array = np.array([12, 13, 17])`

Any approaches that are more efficient than looping through the `sortby` array like below?

```
sorted_array = []
for vals in sortby:
     sorted_array.append(mydict[vals])

return np.array(sorted_array)
```

Comment: Try OrderedDict: docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list comprehension,

```
In [100]: np.array([mydict[i] for i in sortby])
Out[100]: array([12, 13, 17])
```

**Edit:**

Execution timings, To make clear for mohammad and Moses Discussions

```
In [119]: def test_loop():
    sorted_array = []
    for vals in sortby:
        sorted_array.append(mydict[vals])
    return np.array(sorted_array)
   .....: 

In [120]: def test_list_compres():
    return np.array([mydict[i] for i in sortby])
   .....: 

In [121]: %timeit test_list_compres
10000000 loops, best of 3: 20 ns per loop

In [122]: %timeit test_loop
10000000 loops, best of 3: 21.3 ns per loop

In [123]: %timeit test_list_compres
10000000 loops, best of 3: 20.1 ns per loop

In [124]: %timeit test_loop
10000000 loops, best of 3: 21.9 ns per loop
```

It's a marginal difference but it will make a significant change with huge entries.

Comment: The gains here are marginal, but are sure to widen with the size of the dataset